# don't jump to same user-defined chain twice

Tags: iptables, pam

In my `/etc/pam.d/sshd` I have a line:

```
session optional pam_exec.so /usr/local/bin/pam_exec_sshd
```

It calls my script whenever I do ssh login or logout. Script contents:

```
#!/bin/bash
IPTABLES=/usr/sbin/iptables
case $PAM_TYPE in
open_session) act=-I;;
close_session) act=-D;;
*) exit 0;;
esac

$IPTABLES "$act" INPUT -s "$PAM_RHOST" -j PAM_EXEC_SSHD
```

It adds or removes a rule to jump to my custom netfilter chain `PAM_EXEC_SSHD` when a packet of any protocol to any port comes from a valid ssh client host.

If there're 2 or more simultaneous ssh connections from one host, there will be 2+ identical rules in `INPUT` chain - kind of reference counting.

But when we return from `PAM_EXEC_SSHD` back to `INPUT`, if there's another identical rule, we'll jump to `PAM_EXEC_SSHD` again. How to prevent this?

If I change my script to keep only one rule per host, when one of two sessions closes, the only rule for the host will be deleted.